# How to localize server-side data that i get in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using Italian language in my app. I have made a Localizable.string file in English and one in Italian.

It's working OK, and everything is working fine with static data, but there are mostly string responses from the server side. How can I convert them in Italian?

If I get data in different-different any string variable then how I will compare it from localizable.string(Italian).

And I also have server side data in English and Italian language. But in app it comes from server.

Thank you..

Comment: If you have access to the server, you can send it the language have in your app and the Ali respond in right language. The translation of data make server side.

Comment: You are right but i don't have access of server actually i write all text in a file through run app again and again..

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this question. Is there anyone who has idea?

Answer (score -1):

you can get your application current language like this :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *appleLanguagesArray = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

// Get Current language of an application...
NSString *currentLanguage = [appleLanguagesArray objectAtIndex:0];
if(currentLanguage==@"en") {
    // English language.
}
```

The other option is if you have two buttons for two languages, then you can check currently which language is selected.